# Testcafe how to declare ClientFunction in Factory page

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to declare a ClientFunction on a Factory page and then call it on a test page. But I am doing something wrong and it doesn’t work. I have two pages  one  is factory page, second test page.
In test page i have ClientFunction and it works fine. When i trying move to Factory Page it doesn't working.

```
import {Selector, ClientFunction} from "testcafe";
import videoPage from "../pages/video_player_page";

const videoElement = Selector("#bod-video-player_html5_api");

const currentTime = ClientFunction(() => {
  return videoElement().currentTime;
}, {dependencies: {videoElement}});

test
    .page(`some video page url`)
    ("Verify video functionality in LO State ", async (t) => {
     let m1 = currentTime();
           console.log("m1 = " + m1);
      await t
          .click(videoPage.fwdButton)
          .expect(videoPage.videoPlayer.hasClass("vjs-seeking")).notOk();
          let m2 = currentTime();
          console.log("m2 = " + m2);
      await t.expect(m2).gt(m1+25, "fwd button not working");
});
```

in factory page i have

```
import {Selector, t, ClientFunction} from "testcafe";
import {selectors} from "../constants/video_player_page_constants";
import {errorMessages} from "../constants/error_messages/video_player_page_messages";

class VideoPlayerPage {
  constructor() {
    this.skipAd = Selector(`${selectors.skipAdLocator}`, {timeout: 50000});
    this.waiverModal = Selector(`${selectors.warningModalInVideoLocator}`);
    this.videoPlayer = Selector(`${selectors.videoPlayerLocator}`);
    this.videoPlaying = selectors.videoPlaying;
    this.videoPaused = selectors.videoPaused;
    this.waiverModalCheckbox = Selector(`${selectors.warningModalCheckbox}`);
    this.waiverModalCheckboxCss = selectors.warningModalCheckbox;
    this.acceptButton = Selector(`${selectors.warningModalAcceptButton}`);
    this.playPauseButton = Selector(`${selectors.playPauseButtonLocator}`);
    this.fwdButton = Selector(`${selectors.fwdButtonLocator}`);
    this.bwdButton = Selector(`${selectors.bwdButtonLocator}`);
    this.videoElement = Selector("#bod-video-player_html5_api");
  }


  async acceptWaiver() {
    await t
        .expect(this.waiverModal.exists).ok(errorMessages.warningModalNotExist)
        .hover(this.waiverModalCheckboxCss)
        .click(this.waiverModalCheckbox)
        .click(this.acceptButton);
  }

  async skipAdd() {
    if (await this.skipAd.visible) {
      await t.click(this.skipAd);
    }
  }

} export default new VideoPlayerPage();
```

How to declare a ClientFunction on the Factory page, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

class VideoPlayerPage {
    currentTime () {
        return ClientFunction(() => {
            const videoEl = document.querySelector('#bod-video-player_html5_api');
            return videoEl.currentTime;
        })();
    }
}
```

> When I trying move to Factory Page it doesn't work.

I guess that's because you export only an instance of VideoPlayerPage, so if you just copy & paster your ClientFunction code, than it's not exported in the first place, so you can't use it in your test file.

EDIT:

If you want to send a selector to ClientFunction as a parameter, this is the way to do it:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

class VideoPlayerPage {
    constructor () {
        this.videoSelector = '#bod-video-player_html5_api';
    }

    currentTime () {
        return ClientFunction(selector => {
            const videoEl = document.querySelector(selector);
            return videoEl.currentTime;
        })(this.videoSelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional information on this suggestion. I am not good at javascript objects, trying to do something but failing.

Comment: @hamona: Ok, I updated my answer. But I think you should try learn it, it's much better than copy&pasting code from SO. Also, if something doesn't work, always share more details including error messages. I'm not sitting at your side, so I don't really know what problems you're running against.

Comment: hi, i try your solution, its failing because that function return [object Object], but should be number. 
`code
m1 = [object Object]

m2 = [object Object]

 ✖ Verify 'Play Simple workout' functionality in LO State

   1) AssertionError: not bigger: the argument to above must be a number   code`

This is a screenshot with an error.                         
https://i.imgur.com/dDdIOEK.png

Comment: ClientFunction returns a Promise, see the example in the documentation (https://testcafe.io/documentation/402671/reference/test-api/clientfunction). If you want to wait until the Promise resolves, you have to await it.

Comment: ok thanks, everything works. Thanks for the help. And the last question :). How can I in "document.querySelector" insert constructor variable. right here...
 'code videoEl = document.querySelector('#bod-video-player_html5_api'); code'

Comment: @hamona: Good that everything works. I updated my answer again so you can get an answer to your last question.